# Substring should not starts with a word

Tags: regex

I'm using a `RegEx` to extract all `background-images` from a css file.
I simply use a regexp as below:

```
/url\s?+\("?([^\)\"]+)?"?\)/
```

that matches something like `url ("images/bg.jpg")`.
Now i want to ignore background images with absolute URL. So i thought to check if have started with `http` or `https` then ignore it.

But don't know how to edit `RegEx`, I'm programming using `PHP`

Comment: Which tool are you using (Regexes have many dialects)? (And that `\s?+` looks odd: one or more whitespace with minimal matching would be `\s+?`, but since whitespace is optional there I would expect to need `\s*?`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead `(?!http)` to assert that the following chars are not "http":

```
/url\s*\("?(?!http)([^\)\"]+)?"?\)/
```

Comment: Darnit, you're too fast. Tabbed to a regex tester, modified the regex, tabbed back with exactly the same regex. Ah well, +1.

Comment: @Cerbrus A stranger on a plane once said something to me I'll never forget: "There are two types of people; the quick and the have-nots"